# How do I terminate the game below after 30 seconds? I already have 1 timer, so I am not sure how to create a 2nd one and where to put it

Tags: java, oop, timer

How do I terminate the game below after 30 seconds? I already have 1 timer, so I am not sure how to create a 2nd one and where to put it.

I have designed and implemented a game that is simliar to catch the creature (wilbur, in this example). Wilbur appears at a random location for a random duration of time (my first timer), and then disappears to reappear somwhere else. By pressing the mouse button while the pointer is on the image, wilbur is "caught." A count of the number of times Wilbur is caught is dplayed. I have created 3 classes: CatchWilburPanel.java (contains my timer), CatchWilbur.java (the driver), and Wilbur.java.

**CatchWilburPanel.Java**

```
package CatchWilbur;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.util.Random;
    public class CatchWilburPanel extends JPanel
    {
    private Wilbur Wilbur; // instantiates new wilbur object
    private Random gen; // instantiates a new random generator
    private Timer animate; // instantiates a new timer
    public static int seconds = 30;
    private final int X = 20, Y = 100;
    private final int MOVE_ODDS = 4; // 1 in 4 chance Wilbur will move
    private final int DELAY = 500;
    // Sets up the panel
    public CatchWilburPanel()
    {
    Wilbur = new Wilbur(X, Y);
    gen = new Random();
    addMouseListener(new Catcher());
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    animate = new Timer(DELAY, new RandomMover());
    animate.start();
    }
    // Draws wilbur and the number of catches
    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
    super.paintComponent(page);
    // paint wilbur here
    Wilbur.draw(this, page);
    // Update the hit counter for catches and/or misses
    String catchString = "Catches: " + Wilbur.getCatchCount();
    page.drawString(catchString, 10, 20);
    String missString = "Misses: " + Wilbur.getMissCount();
    page.drawString(missString, 10, 40);
    }
    // Inner class listens for mouse presses. If mouse is pressed inside Wilbur,
    // move Wilbur and repaint the screen.
    public class Catcher extends MouseAdapter
    {
    private final int X = 20, Y = 100;
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
    {
    if (Wilbur.pointInMe(event.getX(), event.getY()))
    {
    Wilbur.move(getSize());
    }
    repaint();
    }
    }
    // Inner class listens for timer to move Wilbur & repaint screen during animation.
    // Moves Wilbur based on MOVE_ODDS (may not move every time timer fires).
    public class RandomMover implements ActionListener
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
    int shouldMove = gen.nextInt(MOVE_ODDS);
    if (shouldMove == 0)
    {
    Wilbur.move(getSize());
    repaint();
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

**CatchWilbur.Java**

```
// driver class
package CatchWilbur;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class CatchWilbur
{
// Displays the main frame of the program.
public static void main(String[] args)
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Catch Wilbur");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(new CatchWilburPanel());
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

**Wilbur.Java**

```
    package CatchWilbur;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.Random;
    public class Wilbur {

    private int X, Y, clickCount, catchCount;
    private ImageIcon wilbur; // instantiasted a new ImageIcon
    private Random gen;

    // Creates Wilbur.
    public Wilbur(int initialX, int initialY)
    {
    wilbur = new ImageIcon("image/Wilbur.png");
    X = X;
    Y = Y;
    clickCount = catchCount = 0;
    gen = new Random();
    }
    // Moves wilbur to a random location within the play area.
    public void move(Dimension area)
    {
    X = gen.nextInt(area.width - wilbur.getIconWidth());
    Y = gen.nextInt(area.height - wilbur.getIconHeight());
    }
    // Returns true if point (x , y) is in wilbur and increments catch count, else
    // returns false.
    public boolean pointInMe(int x, int y) // check whether mouse click catches Wilbur
    {
    clickCount++;
    if (x >= X && x <= X + wilbur.getIconWidth())
    {
    if (y >= Y && y <= Y + wilbur.getIconHeight()) // point is in boudns of Wilbur
    {
    catchCount++;
    return true;
    } else
    {
    return false;
    }
    } else
    {
    return false;
    }
    }
    public int getCatchCount() // return number of times Wilbur has been "caught"
    {
    return catchCount;
    }
    public int getMissCount() // return the number of times Wilbur has been "missed"
    {
    return clickCount - catchCount;
    }
    public void draw(Component panel, Graphics page) // has Wilbur repaint itself
    {
    wilbur.paintIcon(panel, page, X, Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: please only use the snippets **only** to show `HTML`, `CSS`, `Javascript` markup,rules,code. it doesn't make much sense for java and in fact makes it even more difficult to read considering your formatting is off aswell.

Comment: I would create a event object, which had a start tine and duration, on each loop of your main loop, I would check to see how long the event has been running and if it exceeds the duration, trigger the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I terminate the game below after 30 seconds?

All you have to do is create another `Timer` like you already do, anywhere you'd like.

If you place the following code as the first thing in your main, then the application will terminate after 30 seconds.

```
new Timer(30 * 1000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Assuming wilbur is an instance of Wilbur
        System.out.println("Catches: " + wilbur.getCatchCount()); 
        System.out.println("Misses: " + wilbur.getMissCount());

        System.exit(0);
    }
}).start();
```

Since you didn't specify any conditions as to how to terminate it I'm assuming `System.exit(0)` is sufficient.

Comment: This worked for me. Is there a way for me to keep the score up before it closes completely? I would like to use the following, if possible:

System.out.println("Catches: ") + Wilbur.getCatchCount();

Comment: thank you so much. I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days. I didn't even realize I could use system.exit(0); does the 0 reference any time duration by any chance?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean with the last sentence?

Comment: If i were to change to 0 to another number, the system still exits after 30 seconds. i was wondering if the 0 had any significance as far as seconds were concerned.

Comment: Ahh that's what you mean. The `0` in `System.exit` is the exit code. If you notice when the application terminates your console probably says `Process finished with exit code 0`. Thus if some specific error happens you could exit with some specific exit code to know what happened / why the application terminated.

Comment: Just beware, multiple timers don't scale well